# How to send RedirectResponse from a POST to a GET route in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi

I want to send data from `app.post()` to `app.get()` using `RedirectResponse`.

```py
@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse, name='homepage')
async def get_main_data(request: Request,
                        msg: Optional[str] = None,
                        result: Optional[str] = None):
    if msg:
        response = templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', {'request': request, 'msg': msg})
    elif result:
        response = templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', {'request': request, 'result': result})
    else:
        response = templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', {'request': request})
    return response
```

```py
@app.post('/', response_model=FormData, name='homepage_post')
async def post_main_data(request: Request,
                         file: FormData = Depends(FormData.as_form)):
       if condition:
        ......
        ......

        return RedirectResponse(request.url_for('homepage', **{'result': str(trans)}), status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)

    return RedirectResponse(request.url_for('homepage', **{'msg': str(err)}), status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
```

1. How do I send `result` or `msg` via `RedirectResponse`, `url_for()` to `app.get()`?
2. Is there a way to hide the data in the URL either as `path parameter` or `query parameter`? How do I achieve this?

I am getting the error `starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name "homepage" and params "result".` when trying this way.

**Update:**

I tried the below:

```py
return RedirectResponse(app.url_path_for(name='homepage')
                                + '?result=' + str(trans),
                                status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

The above works, but it works by sending the param as `query` param, i.e., the URL looks like this `localhost:8000/?result=hello`. Is there any way to do the same thing but without showing it in the URL?

Comment: Please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804) (you should rather use the method's name in `request.url_for()`, i.e., `get_main_data`). As for hiding the data in the URL, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70946019/17865804).

Comment: I tried. I am getting the same error in both cases. Using a `router` as well. Tried with `get_main_data` also, same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For redirecting from a `POST` to a `GET` method, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804) answer on how to do that and the reason for using `status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER` (example is given below).

As for the reason for getting `starlette.routing.NoMatchFound` error, this is because `request.url_for()` receives `path` parameters, **not** `query` parameters. Your `msg` and `result` parameters are `query` ones; hence, the error.

A solution would be to use a `CustomURLProcessor`, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068465/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) answer, allowing you to pass both `path` (if need to) and `query` parameters to the `url_for()` function and obtain the URL. As for hiding the `path` and/or `query` parameters from the URL, you can use a similar approach to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70946019/17865804) that uses [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) (or [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)) to replace the URL in the browser's address bar.

Complete working example can be found below (you can use your own `TemplateResponse` in the place of `HTMLResponse`).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse
from typing import Optional
import urllib

app = FastAPI()

class CustomURLProcessor:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.path = "" 
        self.request = None

    def url_for(self, request: Request, name: str, **params: str):
        self.path = request.url_for(name, **params)
        self.request = request
        return self
    
    def include_query_params(self, **params: str):
        parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path))
        parsed[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        return urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)
        

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def event_msg(request: Request, msg: Optional[str] = None):
    if msg:
        html_content = """
        <html>
           <head>
              <script>
                 window.history.pushState('', '', "/");
              </script>
           </head>
           <body>
              <h1>""" + msg + """</h1>
           </body>
        </html>
        """
        return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
    else:
        html_content = """
        <html>
           <body>
              <h1>Create an event</h1>
              <form method="POST" action="/">
                 <input type="submit" value="Create Event">
              </form>
           </body>
        </html>
        """
        return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)

@app.post('/')
def event_create(request: Request):
    redirect_url = CustomURLProcessor().url_for(request, 'event_msg').include_query_params(msg="Succesfully created!")
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

### Update 1 - About including query parameters

Regarding adding query params to `url_for()` function, another solution would be using Starlette's [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21), which now provides a method to [`include_query_params`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L141). Example:

```py
from starlette.datastructures import URL

redirect_url = URL(request.url_for('event_msg')).include_query_params(msg="Succesfully created!")
```

### Update 2 - About including query parameters

The [`request.url_for()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/requests.py#L174) function now returns a [`starlette.datastructures.URL`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/483849a466a2bfc121f5a367339e1aa3ed20344b/starlette/datastructures.py#L21) object. Hence, you add query parameters as follows:

```py
redirect_url = request.url_for('event_msg').include_query_params(msg="Succesfully created!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I tried a similar approach.